# Android Firefox webextension copy to Clipboard

Tags: android, android-intent, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to copy a text from firefox android browser, fire an intent and read the system clipboard but in vain.

Does the Clipboard wherein firefox webextension copy differ from the Android system clipboard?
If so, is there any other way?

Also, what are the possible ways of transferring a large blob data from browser to the app. I am currently passing it via intent uri.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the `firefox`'s clipboard is not different than android's. I can tell it since I use `Clip Stack` app and it shows text copied from `firefox` too. This app is open source and maybe you can find how to handle your case by having a look at [its code](https://github.com/heruoxin/Clip-Stack).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will check and accept the answer after verification.

Comment: HI Merka, This is an android app and the copy functionality is provided by android here. I wanted an implicit copy form firefox extension.